# Laravel 5 Failed opening required bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php CentOs

Tags: php, laravel-5, centos6

I have this painful issue in laravel with composer. Composer does not create the `vendor` folder. I've read every single post here in stackoverflow and other pages about this problem, and the solution always was that: I should install the composer in my project folder and update the composer or remove composer and install it again. I did all this suggestions, but nothing works.
When I want to generate `php artisan key:generate` it shows me this:

[image]

what can I do? what it's wrong? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you had failed the installation. In my case, there was a php extension missing called php-xml. I'm using php 5.6 on centos so here is the command to install that missing package:

```
yum -y install php56w-xml.x86_64
```

After that, I can install laravel just fine.